# Brunei Passport, UK Residence + Permit, trying to go on a cruise in the Caribbean - double check my conclusion?

Tags: visas, usa, caribbean, brunei

I have a Brunei passport (I am a Brunei citizen) living and working in England, UK (I have ILR and a Biometric residence permit).

My travel itinerary and Visa research returns the following. Can anyone help me double check or point me at resources?

1) USA - ESTA [ http://www.esta.us/brunei.html ]

I've done this before in the past, I hope it shouldn't be a problem.

edit - official site [ https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov ] provided by commenter

2) Half Moon Cay (Bahamas) - No Visa required

[ http://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/wcm/connect/bf838397-2677-410e-9987-87fa188e4966/Visa+Requirements+for+Visitors+Travelling+to+The+Bahamas1.pdf?MOD=AJPERES ]

3) St. Thomas Island (US Virgin Islands) - Same as USA

[ http://www.frommers.com/destinations/virgin-islands/planning-a-trip/entry-requirements--customs ]

Question - if I have a Visa Waiver from visiting the US, would it apply here?

4) San Juan (Puerto Rico)

- same as USA [https://www.worldtravelguide.net/guides/caribbean/puerto-rico/passport-visa/ ]

5) Grand Turk (Turks and Caicos) - This one I'm not sure.

i) http://turksandcaicostourism.com/immigration-turks-and-caicos-entry-requirements/

ii) https://www.visittci.com/travel-info/passports-and-visas
The link in ii) suggests that I don't need an additional visa, as I already have ILR for the UK
Seems like I need to apply for a rather expensive Visa even just for a quick visit?

Comment: Note that esta.us is not an official government website. It's an unofficial site that will charge you an extra $83 "processing fee." You should only apply through the official ESTA site at [https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) and avoid all unofficial sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good on you; you've certainly done your homework, and this will point you to a tool that will confirm your research, and make it easier.  Sourced and provided by the International Air Transport Association (IATA), the [Timatic database](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=BN&NV=Brunei+Darussalam&AC=GB&AV=United+Kingdom&DC=US&DV=United+States&TC=BS%2cPR%2cVI%2cTC&TV=Bahamas%2cPuerto+Rico%2cUS+Virgin+Islands%2cTurks+and+Caicos+Islands&h=ef4dc66868809e23f1925c8192d926f63fffb7) is used by carriers to verify passenger documentation requirements (this via the Emirates portal, as it is particularly user-friendly).

Nationality Brunei Darussalam
Foreign resident of United Kingdom
Destination United States
Transit countries Puerto Rico, US Virgin Islands, Bahamas, Turks and Caicos Islands

**USA, Puerto Rico, US Virgin Islands**

> Visa Exemptions: Nationals of Brunei Darussalam with a biometric passport and an [Electronic System for Travel Authorization (ESTA)](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/). They must travel as a tourist, on business or in transit, for a maximum stay of 90 days.
>
> Passengers must have an ESTA authorization obtained at https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/ and are advised to check their ESTA status prior to travel.
>
> Visitors must hold a return/onward ticket to qualify for a visa exemption.

**Bahamas (BS)**

> Visa Exemptions: Nationals of Brunei Darussalam for a maximum stay of 3 months

**Turks and Caicos Isl.** (TC)

> Visa Exemptions: Passengers with a residence permit issued by United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 90 days.

In summary, you need to [apply through Electronic System for Travel Authorization](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/). With that approval, your passport, and your UK biometric residence permit, you will be good to go.